# Ruby: has_one relationship with foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "EmployeeRecord" and it has a field called username, There is another model called "Employee" with a field called username.

I want to create an association between the 2 models so when I do:

```
record = EmployeeRecord.find(1)
record.employee // returns Employee instance
```

I was thinking I'd just need to do this, but apparently it doesn't work:

```
class EmployeeRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :employee, :foreign_key: username
end
```

Assume I can't add an employee_id field to EmployeeRecord. I scoured the Rails tutorials.. and recall wanting to know how to do this months ago.. but those dang Rails tutorials glided over this.. I remember.. it made me very very angry hehe

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll also need to specify the primary_key used for the association, or else it's defaulted to "id". Your statement actually says "*Search for a field username in table employee that is equal to my id field*". What you actually want is "*Search for a field username in table employee that is equal to my username field*"

This should do the trick :

```
class EmployeeRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :employee, :foreign_key => username, :primary_key => :username
end
```

But hey... Why don't you use ids?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. I wish you good karma, my friend.

Comment: To add, having the foreign_key on both allows you to also do: `employee.record`. Sorry, I had forgotten to use the declaration on both relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Add the foreign key option in the belongs_to method in your Employee model.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee_record, foreign_key: username
end
```

The has_one or has_many is the parent, so it doesn't store the foreign key value/column. That's what the child does that has the belong_to side of the relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't do record.employee